# I want to pass an array to another class, then access specific items in the array to calculate average, maximum or minimum

Tags: java, arrays, oop, methods

This class is used to store the name of the phenomenon to an array.    How do I pass the array to the Collator class to be able to get the average of a phenomenon?

```
public class MonitoringStation {
    // Instance variables
    private String name;
    private Collator[] phenomena;
    private String phenomenonName;
    private double reading;
    private double average_value;
    private double sum;

    Collator collatorObject = new Collator(name);

    // Constructors
    public MonitoringStation(String name, String[] phenomenaNames) {
        // Create a MonitoringStation with the given name that will record statistics for the given phenomena.
        this.name = name;
        phenomena = new Collator[phenomenaNames.length];
        // System.out.println(phenomena.length);
    }

    // Methods
    public void recordReading(String phenomenonName, double reading) {
        // Update the records for the given phenomenon
        collatorObject.recordReading(reading);
        this.reading = reading;
        this.phenomenonName = phenomenonName;
    }

    public double average(String phenomenonName) {
        // Get the current value.
        return average_value;
    }
}
```

This class is the main program that takes in the measurements for the phenomenon.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//
public class StationUI {

    private StationUI() {}

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Monitoring Station Test Harness");
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the station name:");
        final String stationName = scanner.nextLine().trim();

        System.out.println("Enter a comma separated list of the phenomena to be recorded:");
        final String[] phenomena = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s*,\\s*");

        final MonitoringStation station = new MonitoringStation(stationName, phenomena);

        System.out.println("\nMake a selection and press return:");
        System.out.println("0.  Quit");
        System.out.println("1.  Record a phenomenon measurement.");
        System.out.println("2.  View the average reading for a phenomeon.");

        int selection = scanner.nextInt();

        while (selection!=0) {
            if (selection==1) {
                System.out.println("Enter the phenomenon name and value (e.g. 'temperature 7'):");
                if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    final String phenomenon = scanner.next();
                    if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                        final double reading = scanner.nextDouble();
                        station.recordReading(phenomenon, reading);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Couldn't process phenomenon reading. Something wrong?");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't process phenomeon name. Something wrong?");
                }                
            }
            else if (selection==2) {
                System.out.println("Enter the phenomenon name:");
                if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    final String phenomenon = scanner.next();
                    System.out.printf("The average value for phenomeon %s is %.2f.\n", phenomenon , station.average(phenomenon));
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't process phenomeon name. Something wrong?");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("That selection was not recognised.");
            }

            System.out.println("\nMake a selection and press return:");
            System.out.println("0.  Quit");
            System.out.println("1.  Record a phenomenon measurement.");
            System.out.println("2.  View the average reading for a phenomeon.");

            selection = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

The Collator class handles the values and gets the average values, minimum and maximum values recorded and the number of readings for a phenomenon.

```
/**
 * A Collator object stores statistics on a series 
 * of readings, specifically, the number, maximum, minimum, and average.
 * A Collator has a label, usually the name of the phenomenon that the readings
 * represent e.g. temperature, pressure.
 */
public class Collator {

    private final String label;
    private int numReadings;
    private double average;
    private double maximum;
    private double minimum;

    public Collator(final String label) {
        this.numReadings = 0;
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String label() { return label; } 

    public void recordReading(final double reading) {
        if (numReadings<1) {
            // This must be the first reading
            this.average = reading;
            this.maximum = reading;
            this.minimum = reading;
            this.numReadings = 1;
        }
        else {
            // Calculate the current total
            double total;
            total = this.average*this.numReadings;

            // Calculate the new total and update the number of readings
            total = total+reading;
            this.numReadings++;

            // Calculate the new average
            this.average = total/this.numReadings;

            // Check for a new maximum
            if (reading>this.maximum) {
                this.maximum = reading;
            }

            // Check for a new minimum
            if (reading<this.minimum) {
                this.minimum = reading;
            }
        } 
    }

    public double maximum() {
        assert this.numReadings>0 : "Collator:maximum(): number of readings is zero.";
        return this.maximum;
    }

    public double minimum() {
        assert this.numReadings>0 : "Collator:minimum(): number of readings is zero.";
        return this.minimum;
    }

    public double average() {
        assert this.numReadings>0 : "Collator:average(): number of readings is zero.";
        return this.average;
    }

    public int numberOfReadings() { return this.numReadings; } 
}
```

Sample I/O:

> Monitoring Station Test Harness
>   Enter the station name:
>   Zebra
>   Enter a comma separated list of the phenomena to be recorded:
>   height, width
>   Make a selection and press return:
>   0. Quit
>   1. Record a phenomenon measurement.
>   2. View the average reading for a phenomeon.
>   1
>   Enter the phenomenon name and value (e.g. 'temperature 7'):
>   height 13.6
>   Make a selection and press return:
>   0. Quit
>   1. Record a phenomenon measurement.
>   2. View the average reading for a phenomeon.
>   1
>   Enter the phenomenon name and value (e.g. 'temperature 7'):
>   height 12
>   Make a selection and press return:
>   0. Quit
>   1. Record a phenomenon measurement.
>   2. View the average reading for a phenomeon.
>   1
>   Enter the phenomenon name and value (e.g. 'temperature 7'):
>   width 100
>   Make a selection and press return:
>   0. Quit
>   1. Record a phenomenon measurement.
>   2. View the average reading for a phenomeon.
>   2
>   Enter the phenomenon name:
>   height
>   The average value for phenomeon height is 12.80.
>   Make a selection and press return:
>   0. Quit
>   1. Record a phenomenon measurement.
>   2. View the average reading for a phenomeon.
>   0

Comment: There's so many nice container classes in Java, why do folks always use arrays?

Comment: Probabily because they are beginners, and they must learn from the simplest.

Comment: @pk There are some things in your structure I don't understand: `MonitoringStation` contains a `Collator` object (which should be initialized within MonitoringStation's constructor, to access `name` when it has already a value), and also an array of Collators, which isn't used at  all. Are both necessary? Moreover: Could you explain what is the expected relations between your entiries, kind of "MonitoringStation _has_ one Collator, Collator _has_ several DontKnowWhats...".

Answer (score 0):

Just make a public method that receives the array and calculate stuff, like this:

```
public double calculateAverage(double[] arraysName){

    //calculate it using the arraysName

    return average;
}
```

So here you can call it when you have the object created that has this method.
I'm not sure this is the answer you wanted, seems pretty basic to me if you already did that code you posted, I may have the wrong idea.